# Cannot view XML input using XSL style sheet

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

i got this error. Can  anyone help me?

```
  <DiscountedPrice>1.449,00</DiscountedPrice> 
  <Brand /> 
  <Description>LTD32T28NUK 81 EKRAN HISENSE LED TV</Description> 
"Cannot view XML input using XSL style sheet"


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Tag is not closed. 'http://localhost/modules/productlist.ashx' ERROR  Row 2, Colon 2055 

&lt;MARQUEE style="WIDTH: 312px; HEIGHT: 30px" direction=right&gt;&lt;FONT size=3&gt;En Düşük&amp;nbsp;F...
V>
  <IsStocked>0</IsStocked> 
  <Comment /> 
  <Slogan /> 
  <IsFreeTransportation>0</IsFreeTransportation>
```

Comment: You are probably going to have to show more of the xml; the xml shown seems fine...

Comment: What's at line 2 Column 2055?

Answer (score 0):

`&lt;MARQUEE` - something has escaped the opening tag's first character. It isn't recognising the opener as a tag at all, so the parser is getting confused. Open this tag correctly and I bet the problem will go away.